# dynamic dsl using kotlin with content assist

Tags: kotlin

Does kotlin help building the following dsl ?

```
test 'test_01' {
  description " test that a user by name tom is present
  author : xyz
  GET /userstore/users/user(name=tom) {
     verify(/first-name == 'Tom')
  }
}
```

in this dsl, the following are static parts

> test, description, author, GET, verify

but, the expression

> /userstore/users/user(name=tom)

is to be supported dynamically. Meaning, the application knows about various domain models that are navigable by the '/' separated syntax. the IDE (Intellij), should give me the content assist when I invoke it . For example, after GET if I type a '/' and invoke ca , it should give me the following options

1. userstore
2. bookstore
3. buildings
   etc

The fact is, I do not not know these entries at development time. I can write code that can return these entries. I need the editor to invoke my code and get the content assist candidates.

And, I need the build to flag errors if the expression is formed with invalid tokens. So, I need the editor to keep checking with my code and when a token is not found in the returned list of candidates should flag error in the editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the syntax of your example is not valid Kotlin, so no, you can't build it as a Kotlin DSL. If you could change the syntax so that the path is stored in a string literal, then this would be valid Kotlin.

Second, you can build a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA which would provide this kind of content assist and on-the-fly validation for any language - Java, Kotlin or anything else. The effort required to build such a plugin doesn't depend much on the language you're supporting; using Kotlin won't make it any easier to create such a plugin.

Comment: So, what you are hinting is: adjust the syntax towards a host language (kotlin/Groovy) and extend the editors content assist for only the bits of syntax (for ex, the path expression).

Comment: Yes, you could do that.